# Matplotlib: How to plot this? Is it possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is a draft of the output i would like, made by me on draw.io

[image]

Basically my conditions are:

(1) A bar may not start on the first value of the axis Y

(2) The bars are calculated for a interval, so if possible drawing the bars 'inside' that interval

(3) A bar may not have values for a interval, so it's not drawn

Finally, i believe 2 and 3 are possible, but 1 is it? And shall i approach it as a histogram, a bar chart or a box plot? Or maybe a mix? (i am pretty newbie on matplolib)

Any question ask, and thanks.

Comment: one thought: make stacked barcharts and set the color of the bars you want to hide to white: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

Comment: The documentation says that `bar` returns a container with all artists. If you cannot set the desired bars to white within the function call, it might be possible to alter the artists afterwards (within the container object): https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

Comment: The plot you show is not problem to achieve with a usual `plt.bar` plot, but the nonlinear axis labels would need to be defined manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually draw rectangles with matplotlib, so it's not a problem to support (1), (2) and (3) at the same time :)

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html